# How to get inclusive result from Guava RangeSet difference?

Tags: java, range, guava

```
ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet1 = ImmutableRangeSet.of(Range.closed(1, 10));
ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet2 = ImmutableRangeSet.of(Range.closed(3, 6));
ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> result = rangeSet1.difference(rangeSet2);
```

The result of the difference of rangeSet1 and rangeSet2 is `[[1..3), (6..10]]`

But I need to get a result with inclusive ranges: `[[1..2], [7..10]]`

Comment: You can always call `.canonicalize` on the ranges to get a closed-open range, and then normalize from there however you want.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Where's that method?

Comment: On Range itself.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not seeing it. Can you give me a link?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create `ContiguousSet` from each range of `RangeSet`  to convert to a closed range.

```
    ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet1 = ImmutableRangeSet.of(Range.closed(1, 10));
    ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet2 = ImmutableRangeSet.of(Range.closed(3, 6));

    ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> difference = rangeSet1.difference(rangeSet2);
    ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> closedRangeSet = difference.asRanges().stream()
            .map(range -> {
                DiscreteDomain<Integer> domain = DiscreteDomain.integers();
                return ContiguousSet.create(range, domain).range(BoundType.CLOSED, BoundType.CLOSED);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(toSet(), ImmutableRangeSet::copyOf));

    System.out.println(closedRangeSet);
```